# Hadoop - Insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment while starting YARN service

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, jvm, hadoop-yarn

I have set up a cluster (1-master & 2-slaves(slave1, slave2)) based on the tutorial http://pingax.com/install-apache-hadoop-ubuntu-cluster-setup. When I ran for the first time both `HDFS` & `YARN` services ran without any problem. But when I stopped an ran them again, I got the following while running `YARN` service (`start-yarn.sh`) from the master.

```
# starting yarn daemons
# starting resourcemanager, logging to /local/hadoop/logs/yarn-dev-resourcemanager-login200.out
# 
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 168 bytes for AllocateHeap
# An error report file with more information is saved as: /local/hadoop/hs_err_pid21428.log

Compiler replay data is saved as: /local/hadoop/replay_pid21428.log
slave1: starting nodemanager, logging to /local/hadoop/logs/yarn-dev-nodemanager-login198.out
slave2: starting nodemanager, logging to /local/hadoop/logs/yarn-dev-nodemanager-login199.out
slave2: #
slave2: # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
slave2: # Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 168 bytes for AllocateHeap
slave2: # An error report file with more information is saved as:
slave2: # /local/hadoop/hs_err_pid27199.log
slave2: #
slave2: # Compiler replay data is saved as:
slave2: # /local/hadoop/replay_pid27199.log
```

Based on the suggestions from [out of Memory Error in Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464048/out-of-memory-error-in-hadoop) and ["Java Heap space Out Of Memory Error" while running a mapreduce program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30295606/java-heap-space-out-of-memory-error-while-running-a-mapreduce-program), I varied the `heap memory` size limit to 256, 512, 1024 & 2048 in all the 3 files `~/.bashrc`, `hadoop-env.sh` and `mapred-site.sh` but nothing worked.

Note: I'm not an expert on Linux nor JVM.

Log file contents from one of the nodes:

```
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 32784 bytes for Chunk::new
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (allocation.cpp:390), pid=16375, tid=0x00007f39a352c700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_102-b14) (build 1.8.0_102-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.102-b14 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Core dump written. Default location: /local/hadoop/core or core.16375 (max size 1 kB). To ensure a full core dump, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

CPU:total 1 (1 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 45 stepping 2, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, aes, clmul, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv

Memory: 4k page, physical 2051532k(254660k free), swap 1051644k(1051324k free)
```

Comment: This would happen if there is enough space for the heap but not the rest of the memory the program needs to run. I would look at the memory usage dump in the log file.

Comment: How much physical memory do you have on each node ?

Comment: 2Gigs of memory on each server. If that is the case if I increase the memory should it fix the problem?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I've added the log file contents from one of the nodes. Should I try all the possible solutions?

Comment: So you have 1 CPU and 2 GB of memory. You need to make sure every JVM is using as little memory as possible. There could be more than one so you have to make sure your setting applies to all of them.

Comment: Btw my phone has more processing power. Is this a good choice for big data?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I totally agree to your point and I can increase the RAM capacity to make this up and running. But I have had this cluster set up with the same amount of physical RAM on a 3 virtual machines using virtual box. So I was just curious why it is not running on 3 physical servers.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your post how much memory the VM itself has, but it seems like the VM has only 2GB of physical memory and 1GB of swap. If that be the case, you are going to **really** increase the memory of the VM. Absolutely nothing less than 4GB of physical memory or you'll be lucky to get the Hadoop stack running and keep the OS happy at the same time. Ideally, set each VM to about 8GB of RAM to ensure you have a few GB of RAM to throw at the MapReduce jobs.